# How do I specify the port to connect to Launchpad code?

Tags: port, bazaar

My server uses a non-standard SSH port (not 22) for connections and now I am trying to grab some code from Launchpad and it keeps erroring out because it's trying to connect to the server with my SSH port number rather than the standard port 22. I've searched online for a bit and found ways to specify the port for a standard bazaar URL, such as this:

```
bzr branch bzr+ssh://user@ip:port/path/to/program
```

But LaunchPad seems to be slightly different in which I don't know where I'd specify the port.

```
bzr branch lp:~registry/program/build
```

I tried putting the `:22` after the `~` but that didn't work (still tried to connect on non-standard port). Any idea how I'd grab things from Launchpad through port 22?

(Sorry if this belongs on SU, the guidelines between the two seem rather confusing.)

Comment: Do you have a .ssh/config that is changing the default port you are connecting to? Changing the port the server listens on, should not do anything to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure seems like you could just setup an `.ssh/config` file with a valid entry for the host, and it should be used.

```
Host {hostname} # you could also use an alias here
  Hostname {ip}
  Port {port}
```